# SQL Multiple conditions (AND, OR) in WHERE clause yield incorrect result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I just want to return a list from table where date difference more than 15 days are returned. It only returns where `RequestStatus=1` not getting from where `RequestStatus=2`.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM User 
WHERE RequestStatus = 1 
   OR RequestStatus = 3 
  AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), TaskCompletionDate)) > 15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a SQL `IN` clause to specify all legitimate values for `RequestStatus` column in your `WHERE` condition like

```
Select * 
from User 
Where RequestStatus in (1,2,3)
and (DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), TaskCompletionDate))> 15
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest writing the query as:

```
select *
from User
Where RequestStatus in (1, 2, 3) and
      TaskCompletionDate > DATEADD(day, 15, getdate())
```

By moving `TaskCompletionDate` outside the date functions, you give SQL Server more opportunities to optimize the query (for instance, by potentially making use of an index, if available and appropriate).

Comment: +1. It might have been even more helpful to the question OP if you'd focused the explanations on how to combine several conditions, and on the use of `IN`; optimization is important, too, but probably not the OP's primary concern at this time.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Select * from User Where (RequestStatus=1 or RequestStatus=3) and (DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), TaskCompletionDate))> 15
```

Comment: +1 @Gordon I solved only problem of bracket but he optimized the query.... sorry, I have no much reputation to write in your answer